# Android - drawable scaling for tablet

Tags: android, android-resources

I have a background image defined in *res/drawable-hdpi*, and it looks fine on all phones, it's a standard 480x800 image that scales well for other screens with similar aspect ratio. The image of course fits pixel-perfect on 480x800 phone.

Now I've bought a 7" tablet that also has 480x800 screen, but is a **large** screen. 
Although the image itself IS 480x800 and tablet has the *same resolution*, the image looks like it was downscaled to smaller size and then upscaled again.

I have a temporary solution that works - to place the same image into res/drawable-large folder, which works, but I have the same image twice in my project which I think is unnecessary.

**I suspect** it has to do with the image being in res/drawable-hdpi, and because the tablet is MDPI, it did some scaling down and scaling up, but I'd like to avoid this and do it properly, so I can use the same drawable in one folder, and it will work correctly on phones and tablets.

Comment: you can put that particular image in  "drawable" folder.

Comment: @AbhayKumar make it an answer, it's correct

Comment: FYI, Nexus 7 is not 480x800 as mentioned, its 1280x800

Comment: @AjithMemana why are you talking about nexus 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put that particular image in "drawable" folder.

Comment: Hi Abhay, Axerydax I put particular image in drawable folder but i also down/up scaled. I'm developing app for using full assets oriented one. I was get the all assets for 1920x1080 size images. How it will support all android devices? or How can i use images? what size support mobile and tablet? Please help me, i struggled. Thanks in advance.